# Windows 7 installed on a separate drive won't boot from GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

Just installed Ubuntu MATE on my machine at work, as a dual boot (was planning on keeping Windows as I have to occasionally write C#, although I'm a Linux user).

GRUB will boot into Ubuntu fine but not Windows 7. When I try to boot into Windows 7 the screen goes crazy and freezes, sorta half grey half black.

My work system is a 250gb SSD with a 1TB HDD. Windows is installed on the SSD. When I installed ubuntu, it would only let me install on the HDD. So i gave 500GB of that to Ubuntu installation.

My BIOS will only let me select the SSD as a boot drive, and won't let me use the HDD as a boot drive.

I'm tempted to edit the Windows GRUB boot entry and remove chain loader and replace with ntdlr - will this work?

Answer (score 1):

The solution editing the grub entry for windows 7, by pressing <kbd>e</kbd> on it in the menu.

I added:

```
insmod ntldr
```

to the top.

I removed:

```
chainloader +1
```

from the bottom

Finally I added:

```
ntldr ($root)/bootmgr
```

to the bottom.

I still got the grey and black screen but hitting <kbd>esc</kbd> on this brought up a blinking cursor and then the Windows boot menu! hurrah!

I got my information from [this post on the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230300)

Thought it might help others.

*The strange part is: changes to the GRUB entry don't persist between boots. BUT now whenever I click on the Windows 7 entry, I go straight into the Windows 7 bootloader, without having to edit the entry again??? This is one of those "i don't know why it's not working", "now its working and i don't know why it is working" things haha*